# Create view and show max value - mimer sql

Tags: sql, mimer-sql

I would like to create a view that presents name and number of a "department" with the max value.

```
drop view highestvalue;

CREATE VIEW HighestValue AS SELECT s.dept, d.name, SUM(s.quantity) TotalQuantity
FROM sale AS s
INNER JOIN dept AS d ON d.number = s.dept
GROUP BY s.dept, d.name
ORDER BY TotalQuantity;

select * from HighestValue;
```

Expected result:

Defined view with name and number of the department with most sold items

Answer (score 2):

If you want only one row, and your DBMS's version is `10.1+` then use `fetch first`:

```
CREATE VIEW HighestValue AS
    SELECT s.dept, d.name, SUM(s.quantity) TotalQuantity
    FROM sale s INNER JOIN
         dept d
         ON d.number = s.dept
    GROUP BY s.dept, d.name
    ORDER BY TotalQuantity
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: Im using mimer sql, that didnt do the work for me, doesnt give me highest value, i added desc and fetched the first row, but i dont think thats the best way to do it?

Comment: @Boohz12 . . . http://download.mimer.com/pub/developer/docs/html_101/Mimer_SQL_Engine_DocSet/select_spec.html.

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this

```
CREATE VIEW HighestValue AS SELECT s.dept, COUNT(d.number) totalDepartments, SUM(s.quantity) TotalQuantity
FROM sale AS s
INNER JOIN dept AS d ON d.number = s.dept
GROUP BY s.dept
ORDER BY TotalQuantity;
```